# SNMP4J: Can't get SNMPv3 to work with multiple targets

Tags: snmp4j

I'm trying to use SNMP4J (v2.6.2) to query (snmpget) two different target
machines at once. I've tried two approaches, and it always only
receives a response for the first target.  Whichever one I query
second never gets a response.  (I can query both machines from the
command line just fine, including separately and simultaneously.)  One
approach I tried uses one `Snmp`, one `Transport`, and two `UserTarget`s.
The other approach uses two `Snmp`s, two `Transport`s, and two
`UserTarget`s.  They both behave the same.  I also get the same effect
if I send one request, wait until that one's finished, and then send
the second one.

I've written a minimal example and pasted it below.  Perhaps someone
can give me a hint about what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks!

```
package snmpclienttext;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.snmp4j.PDU;
import org.snmp4j.ScopedPDU;
import org.snmp4j.Snmp;
import org.snmp4j.TransportMapping;
import org.snmp4j.UserTarget;
import org.snmp4j.event.ResponseEvent;
import org.snmp4j.event.ResponseListener;
import org.snmp4j.mp.MPv3;
import org.snmp4j.mp.SnmpConstants;
import org.snmp4j.security.AuthMD5;
import org.snmp4j.security.AuthSHA;
import org.snmp4j.security.PrivAES;
import org.snmp4j.security.SecurityLevel;
import org.snmp4j.security.SecurityModels;
import org.snmp4j.security.SecurityProtocols;
import org.snmp4j.security.TSM;
import org.snmp4j.security.USM;
import org.snmp4j.security.UsmUser;
import org.snmp4j.smi.Address;
import org.snmp4j.smi.GenericAddress;
import org.snmp4j.smi.OID;
import org.snmp4j.smi.OctetString;
import org.snmp4j.smi.VariableBinding;
import org.snmp4j.transport.DefaultUdpTransportMapping;


public class SNMPClientTest {
    static class MySNMP {
        TransportMapping<? extends Address> transport;
        Snmp snmp;
        OctetString securityName;
        static String password = "temppassword";
        UserTarget target;

        void setup(String ip) throws IOException {
            DefaultUdpTransportMapping d = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
            d.setReceiveBufferSize(65536);
            transport = d;
            System.out.println("Listen address: " +
transport.getListenAddress());
            transport.listen();

            snmp = new Snmp(transport);

            OctetString localEngineId = new
OctetString(MPv3.createLocalEngineID());
            USM usm = new USM(SecurityProtocols.getInstance(),
localEngineId, 0);
            SecurityModels.getInstance().addSecurityModel(usm);

            securityName = new OctetString("SHA");
            OID authProtocol = AuthSHA.ID;
            OID privProtocol = org.snmp4j.security.PrivAES128.ID;
            System.out.println("snmpv3password: " + password);
            OctetString authPassphrase = new OctetString(password);
            OctetString privPassphrase = new OctetString(password);

            snmp.getUSM().addUser(securityName, new
UsmUser(securityName, authProtocol, authPassphrase, privProtocol,
privPassphrase));
            SecurityModels.getInstance().addSecurityModel(new
TSM(localEngineId, false));

            target = new UserTarget();
            target.setSecurityLevel(SecurityLevel.AUTH_PRIV);
            target.setSecurityName(securityName);

            target.setAddress(GenericAddress.parse(String.format("udp:%s/%s",
ip, "161")));
            target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version3);
            target.setRetries(0);
            target.setTimeout(60000);
        }

        public void readRequest(String oid) throws IOException {
            PDU pdu = new ScopedPDU();
            pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(oid)));
            pdu.setType(PDU.GET);
            try {
                System.out.println("snmp get for " + target.getAddress());
                snmp.get(pdu, target, null, listener);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("SNMP Fail");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    static ResponseListener listener = new ResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ResponseEvent event) {
            if (event != null) {
                Address addr = event.getPeerAddress();
                if (addr == null) {
                    System.out.println("Null address");
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println("Peer Address = " + addr);
                PDU rpdu = event.getResponse();
                if (rpdu != null) {
                    if (rpdu.getErrorStatus() == PDU.noError) {
                        for (VariableBinding vb : rpdu.getVariableBindings()) {
                            OID oid = vb.getOid();
                            org.snmp4j.smi.Variable var = vb.getVariable();
                            String val = var.toString();
                            if (var.isException()) val = "";
                            System.out.println("Binding for " + oid +
" has " + vb.toString().length() + " characters, var has " +
val.length() + " characters");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Snmp Get Unsuccessful.");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Snmp response is null.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("SNMP event null.");
            }
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
InterruptedException {
        MySNMP a = new MySNMP();
        MySNMP b = new MySNMP();
        a.setup("10.1.2.78");
        b.setup("10.1.2.135");

        a.readRequest("1.3.6.1.4.1.6713.1.3.1.2.1.1.50");
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        b.readRequest("1.3.6.1.4.1.6713.1.3.1.2.1.1.50");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've spent some time digging into this, and what I find is that the
second target queried always comes back with an error of
SNMPv3_USM_NOT_IN_TIME_WINDOW.  I'm not sure how this time window
works, but absolutely every request sent to whichever target is
initialized second gets this error in response.  I'm going to go looking for static variables.

Comment: My guess is that the requests's engine boot counter isn't matching the agent.  Like the boot counter being used for the second agent is taken from the first agent.

Comment: I came across the same problem. Have you found a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Source of the problem is using the same engine ID for the two SNMP entities "a" and "b". Make sure to always use unique engine IDs with SNMPv3.